# Maven project that runs a series of unit tests written in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, maven, jython

I am trying to set up a simple maven project that will run a bunch of unit tests written in Python. I believe I need a plugin for this job and I came across one such plugin - [jython-compile-maven-plugin](http://mavenjython.sourceforge.net/compile/plugin-info.html)

However, I believe that this plugin allows the user to make a call to the "nosetests" command which then runs a bunch of Python scripts that call on JUnit test cases (that is test cases written in Java). What I would like to do is have Maven call the command "nosetests" and run just a bunch of test cases written in Python. Can anyone advise if this is doable? Or can anyone point me in the direction to some docs that can help.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-surefire-plugin` allows specification of a custom test provider (see the [API](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/api.html)).  You tell surefire to use the provider by adding a plugin dependency as shown in the [examples](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html).  They don't mention a provider that runs Python tests, maybe someone else has written one?  If not, maybe you may write it.  The surefire plugin source contains 4 different providers you could use as examples.

Answer (score 0):

The `exec-maven-plugin` can be used to run `nosetests` similar to as described at http://blog.berczuk.com/2009/12/continuous-integration-of-python-code.html